# How to add an existing, external-drive installed, Ubuntu 19.04 to another computer's Windows 10 Boot loader?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, external-hdd, 19.04

I've installed Ubuntu 19.04 on an external SSD on my laptop, alongside my Windows 10 that exists on the laptop's SSD. The setup went smoothly without any problems. I've allocated space for EFI for the Linux installation and my laptop successfully loads into Linux when the external SSD is connected, and into Windows when it's not.

However, I couldn't get to boot into Linux on my main PC. I'm connecting the external SSD (with Linux on it) but I'm failing to boot into it. The methods I've tried taking is:

- Selecting to boot through the external SSD via the boot menu (all it does is go black for a second and then boot into Windows)
- Setting boot to UEFI and Legacy. I couldn't find the "Secure Boot" option in my BIOS though
- Adding an Ubuntu boot option via `bcdedit` - copying Windows' one and setting the path to some `\EFI\...` . I don't remember exactly what I did but I've deleted the entry
- Using EasyBCD. I wasn't sure really on what option I should've used there; Linux was disabled for me (with some error about EFI?) so I didn't want to fiddle with it too much

I'm using the:

- Gigabyte Z77-D3H motherboard for the main PC, the one I'm trying to boot Linux on through the external SSD
- Asus' X556-URK motherboard for my laptop, the one I've installed Linux with

I've been trying to dig for an answer but most answers I've seen do not talk about Ubuntu being installed as a portable OS on an external hard-drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not expect that it works. When you installed Ubuntu on SSD with your laptop, the install was done specifically for the hardware and configuration of your laptop. Thus it cannot work on your main PC because it has different hardware and configuration. Your main PC is also likely to miss bootloader tricks that was done on your laptop while installing Ubuntu (what you've tried to do manually with bcdedit).

If you wish to boot independently on any of your computers, you can set your external SSD as a live system. There is also the option of making it persistent.

Alternatively and if your SSD is big enough, you could set several partitions on it:

- one for laptop system,
- one for main PC system,
- and one for `/home` that would be used by both systems.

Then you could install Ubuntu on both computers. You would need to keep the same username in both systems and use the same `/home` partition. This way you would have the constraint of maintaining 2 distinct systems, but each system would have its drivers, config and bootloader entry, your applications would share the same configurations in the `/home` and your documents would be available on both systems. You could even take advantage of this and use 2 different flavors e.g. Ubuntu on main PC if more powerful and Xubuntu on laptop or so...